# What TLDs can be used with Azure?

Tags: azure, domain, cloud, azure-web-apps, tld

I am a newbie in the Azure world but am planning to use the App service to upload a PHP demo  app. However, I was reading in the documentation that I can buy certain supported domains inside Azure but, Could I use my .app or .co domain already registered with Namecheap or GoDaddy?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Azure App Service Team](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/17984884-expand-the-list-of-the-tlds-that-is-possible-to-bu):

> You can purchase a domain with any TLD from a 3rd party Domain
>   Registrar and set up the DNS to be managed by Azure.

If you would like to [configure it in Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain):

> Select Custom domain names, and then select Add custom domain.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service works fine with domains you have purchased elsewhere, you do not have to purchase them through Azure. To use a domain purchased elsewhere you just need to add a DNS record for the URL you wish to use for your web application, to point to the web application. You can see details of how to do this [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).